# How to get list of current filepaths of changed files since creation of branch

Tags: git

I am trying to get a list of all python files changed in my current branch, this list will later be fed into a script to run a linter. Previously I was doing it by the following command.

```
FORK_POINT=$(git rev-parse origin/master)
PY_FILES=$(git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD $FORK_POINT | grep "\.py$")
```

In my current branch one of my changes is to move some files to another folder, however this code is returning the original filepaths for the moved files. How can I ammend this to return the currernt filepaths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: swap the diff "sides".

---

Your diff command:

```
git [options] diff HEAD [other-commit]
```

asks Git to take two snapshots:

```
HEAD
```

and

```
other-commit
```

and find some reasonably minimal set of changes that, if applied to the *first* commit listed—`HEAD`—will change those files to produce the set of files contained in the *second* commit.  If Git matches up a file named `newname` in the first set with a file named `oldname` in the second set, the instructions include "rename newname to oldname".

To get these instructions in a guaranteed and machine-parse-able way, use:

```
git diff --name-status --find-renames
```

rather than just `git diff --name-only`.  The `status` letter will be `R`, followed by why Git decided those files were sufficiently similar, expressed as a percentage, followed by the two names.

To get instructions that change the old name to the new name, do the diff in the opposite order.  Put the other commit on the *left* side of the [Spot-the-Difference game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference), and put the `HEAD` commit on the *right* side.  Git will again find some reasonably minimal set of changes that, if applied, would turn the left side (old) commit into the right side (new) commit—but since the *old* commit is now the one on the left, these instructions will say "rename oldname to newname".

Note that `--name-only` or `--name-status` suppresses most of the instructions (which itself is fine, and actually speeds up the work of `git diff`).  The order, however, still matters—if only because *rename* instructions put the left-side commit's file name on the left, and the right-side commit's file name on the right.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To summarise, `git --no-pager diff --name-only $FORK_POINT HEAD ` should get all my changes but also display the up to date filepaths for the subset of files that have been moved?

Comment: Yes, with `HEAD` on the right, the `--name-only` names will be the ones shown. I still prefer `--name-status` in general here as the status (usually one of A, D, M, or R) is important as well: you can't check a deleted file's content, for instance!

Comment: Oh, that is a good point! I'll also move to name-status and update the grep to ignore deleted files.